# How to click on <select>?

Tags: javascript

I need to choose the option in select field. I have a code to do this however there is one thing. After clicking the select and choosing the proper option, button appears. My code picks the option but button does not appear. I'm working on automation of one website. I tried to find the way to click the select field but none of the solutions worked. document.getelementbyid.click() as well. Appreciate for any hints.

```
function robber(){
    var final = 0
    var dropDown = document.querySelectorAll("select[id='singlerobbery-select-robbery'] option");
    dropDown.forEach((opcja) =>{
        if (opcja.innerText.includes("100")){
            final++;
        }
    });
    var choose_rob = document.querySelector("select[id='singlerobbery-select-robbery']").selectedIndex = final;
    document.querySelector("button[class='btn btn-inverse']").click(); // this is the button I need to click afterwards

};
```

Comment: Stay away from `"button[class='some classes here']"`, as it won't select `button[class='classes some here']` (it does a simple string comparison, rather than looking at classList). You probably want `document.querySelector('button.btn.btn-inverse')`. Also note this only selects the first element in DOM with those classes. It won't look for a second one.

Comment: Show your html code also, and tell what you want to get exactly

Comment: @AksenP As mentioned, I'm working on automation of one website. I need to select the particular field from select field and then click the button. The above code selects the option, but the website is kinda secured and to display button, click action on the select must be performed.

Comment: You're probably dealing with an execution queue order issue. But, without a [mcve] reproducing it, you're making it really hard for anyone to help you.

Comment: Click event on `<select>` is not practical. To be honest it is not clear at all what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Apologise for answering my own question, but due to many responses I've decided to sum it up in new post. What I'm trying to do is to select the option from select menu and click the button.  [Screen shoot what I need to obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMxc4.jpg)

My above code replaces the content in select but to get this buton I must click on the select field to make it pops out.